# how to connect to a switch connected to serial port

Tags: ubuntu, switch, console, serial

My computer and switch both are connected to network. I need to connect to the console port of switch via serial port on my computer. I am using ubuntu.

How can I do that? How do I know whats the port where I've plugged the serial jack into and how to access it? I need some terminal emulator kind of thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect it to COM1 with a normal serial cable, and connect minicom to `/dev/ttyS0`.

Comment: Minicom is nice, but you might also want to just use `screen`.  Something like `screen /dev/ttyS0 9600` may be what you want.  See http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2008/08/12/using-gnu-screen-to-debug-your-serial-port/

Comment: Zoredache - you are awesome. screen works like a charm.

Comment: Zoredache +1 I didn't know screen could do that....nice tip